# How to Add Multiple Items in DataGridView using Windows Applications?

Tags: c#, windows, combobox

I've just started to use dataGridView.

Here I'm using Combobox and DataGridView in Windows Application c#.

We Selected any items in the Combobox that items will be added on one by one `[rows]` in 
DataGridView Cells.

Selected Items Will be added on `[customername]` Columns.

[image: Form Image]

For Example :

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       Combobox1.Items.Add("Name1");
       Combobox1.Items.Add("Name2");
       Combobox1.Items.Add("Name3");
       Combobox1.Items.Add("Name4");
}
private void cmbpaymentopt_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string item = cmbpaymentopt.SelectedItem.ToString();
        if (item != null)
        {
           //Here Code 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set the rows from the DataGridView using DataSource property

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = _listCustomers;
```

EDIT:

if your dataGridView use bindings then use

```
private static void AddItemToGrid<T>(DataGridView dataGridView, T data)
{
    var dataSource = dataGridView.DataSource as BindingSource;
    dataSource?.Add(data);
}
```

if not, simply use

```
private static void AddItemToGrid(DataGridView dataGridView, params object[] cells)
{
    dataGridView.Rows.Add(cells);
}
```

Comment: Here I'm not using DataSource .I'm just adding the items in Form_load event and we select any items in the Combobox that item will be added to DataGridView columns